# How to remove %20 from Contact Form 7 field

Tags: contact-form-7

My wordpress website capturing url UTM from Google Ads via hidden field of Contact Form 7. But Contact Form 7 capturing keywords with %20 instead of space (Ex. life%20insurance%20policy) and sending to assigned email addresses.

How can I replace %20 with space?

Answer (score 0):

You should make it url decoded value, so if its value saved in hidden input with %20 you’d better to do it via js like this:

```
var form = document.getElementsByClassName('wpcf7-form')[0];
form.addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
    form.elements['google_adv'].value = decodeURIComponent(form.elements['google_adv'].value);
}, { capture: true });
```

But if the changing process is in backend side you may try with php codes instead:

```
    add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'some_function_name', 1 ); 
    function some_function_name( $contact_form ) {
        $wpcf7 = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    
        if ($submission) {
            $data = array();
            $data['posted_data'] = $submission->get_posted_data();
            $google = $data['posted_data']['google_adv']; // just enter the field name here
            $mail = $wpcf7->prop('mail');
    
            if($google !=''){
                $mail['body'] = str_replace($google, urldecode($google), $mail['body']);
   $mail['body'] = str_replace('[google_adv]', urldecode($google), $mail['body']);
            }
    
            $wpcf7->set_properties(array(
                "mail" => $mail
            )); 
    
            return $wpcf7;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer is confusing.  Why are you setting the property `$mail` ?  Why are you getting objects that are already passed to `wpcf7_before_send_mail` and also, you don't return anything to this function, since it's an action and not a filter. in other words, `return $wpcf7` will do nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Howard.

Please suggest me the exact code?